TypeORM postgresql order by enum text value
Trying to order by on an enum field (continent) by its text value on Postgresql. This works nice;
order by
    "Country"."continent"::TEXT DESC

Need to create the same result on TypeORM when I'm setting an orderBy;
orderBy = { ...orderBy, continent: value.sort };

How to to it in TypeOrm?

I know two ways to order by that property.
The first one is using the regular way:
const countries = await CountryEntity.find({
    order: {
        continent: "DESC"
    }
})

The other way (if you find useful the explicit conversion) is this:
const orderBy: OrderByCondition = {
  continent: `CAST("Country"."continent" AS TEXT) ${value.sort}`,
};

const countries = await Country.find({
  order: orderBy,
});

